# Convergence in $l_2$ versus $L_2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-distributions

A summary of my question is
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{Are there sequences that converge in $L_2$ but whose discretization does not converge in $l_2?$}
\end{equation*}
I believe the answer is $\textbf{yes}$ and below is my example. I have a follow-up question at the bottom related to this construction.

Take the domain $I = [-1,1]$. Pick $f \in L_2$. Now say that by "discretization," for each $n$, I want to simply specify to you an increasing set of $S_n$ points $x^{n}_{1} < x^{n}_{2} < ... < x^{n}_{S_n}$ (super script is not exponentiation, just to emphasize different "$x$" for each $n$). Here the implication is that as I take $n \to \infty$, the number of samples I take $S_n$ can grow with $n$ to get a "finer" representation of $f$. Now simply pick 
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) + 1 & x \in \{x_1^{n},...,x_{S_n}^{n}\} \\
f(x) & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Note that $\|f - f_n\|_{L_2} = 0$ for every $n$ since $f,f_n$ differ on a set of measure zero. Now if I consider the vectors 
\begin{equation*}
\textbf{f}_{exact}^{n} = (f(x_1^{n}),...,f(x_{S_n}^{n}))^{T} \\
\textbf{f}_{n}^{n} = (f_n(x_1^{n},...,f_n(x_{S_n}^{n}))^{T}
\end{equation*}
then $\|\textbf{f}_{exact}^{n}-\textbf{f}_{n}^{n}\| = S_n \geq 1$ which does not go to $0$.

The follow-up question is then

What if I also sampled my points in a pathological way so as to hit the exact quadrature points for each step along the way? Hence the sequence $\textbf{would not even converge in the $L_2$ norm}$ up to my ability to do quadrature on a computer!!! My interest in this has to do with how to properly renormalize a discrete approximation to a continuous probability density function.

Comment: There must be some additional hypothesis on $f$. If we are talking about just $f\in L_2$, then we can not attach any meaning to $f(x)$.

Comment: Note that $\ell^2$ is just an $L^2$ space with the counting measure.